# Parameters for the Release Management Deploy Azure App Service step

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a JSON ARM template that I want to use in VSTS Release Management to create my App Service Plan environment for me. I'd like VSTS to use the App service plan name (and resource group if possible) instead of hardcoding a string into the web UI.

I'd like to use the parameter 'hostingPlanName' from my website.json file and put it in the release management UI. Is it possible to do so or is this a feature request?

[image]

website.json now has:
`"variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
    "hostingPlanName": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",...`

website.test.parameters.json

`{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "value": "X-test-plan"
    },
    "webAppName": {
      "value": "X-test-web"
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

No, RM doesn't read the values from JSON. Alternatively, you can define them as variables in the Release Definition environment and use it in the App Service Task.

Answer (score 1):

To override the parameter values defined in the `website.parameters.json` file, please refer to the steps (from **Step 33** to **Step 36**) in this document: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudio2017Launch_KeynoteDemos/tree/master/VSTS%20and%20DevOps.

You need to choose the `website.json` and `website.parameters.json` file in the Azure Resource Group Deployment step. Set **Override template parameters** like this:

`-webAppName $(webApp) -hostingPlanName $(hostingPlan)`

Then create 2 release variables in your release definition named `$(webApp)` and `$(hostingPlan)`. Give the values that you want to use in release to the 2 variables.